# Point falls into a circle in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm having some troubles with elasticSearch finding a point inside a circle. 
Example: Let's say I have 50 records in elastic. I have indexed and created a mapping for each of them like this

```
  .GeoShape(g => g.Name(n => n.BoundingCircle)
                       .Tree(GeoTree.Quadtree)
                       .TreeLevels(50)
                       .DistanceErrorPercentage(0.025)
                    )
```

Where BoundingCircle is a CircleGeoShape. Now for each record i have lat, long and radius so it's easy to build a Circle shape. 
Now my problem is that giving a certain point in the search i can not find if the point is in one of the 50 circle shapes. 
I tried like this :

```
  var result3 = EsClient.Search<Radius>(s => s
            .Filter(f => f
                .GeoShapePoint(
                "boundingCircle",
                 c => c.Coordinates(coord).Relation(GeoShapeRelation.Intersects)
            )
        )
        .Take(50)
        .Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())
        );
```

But it seems that searching a point into a circle shape in elastic is not working.
Somebody managed to do this ?

UPDATE : 
I did managed to find a point into a EnvelopeGeoShape but i would like to use CircleGeoShape

UPDATE:
I used PolygonGeoShape to create the shape of each record because the EnvelopeGeoShape doesn't offer the best coverage. I created an decagon and for small radius the coverage is almost as good as a circle. The ugly part in this was creating the decagon coordinates.
Any way i get back to my question. Did anybody managed to find a point into a CircleGeoShape in elastic search ?

Thanks